# Align function parameters on new line in C# with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, formatting, visual-studio-2017, auto-indent

I want functions parameters to autoindent like this when I place them on a new line

```
        using (MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Global\\PointCloudData", 
                                                                                 capacity, 
                                                                                 MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                                                                                 MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, 
                                                                                 HandleInheritability.Inheritable))
```

But they always align like this

```
            using (MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Global\\PointCloudData", 
                capacity, 
                MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, 
                HandleInheritability.Inheritable))
```

I have managed to get this behavior in c++ on Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise but I can't find it anywhere for c#. Does Visual Studio even allows this? It would be weird if it didn't, but I've looked and I can't find it at all.

Comment: you can use ctrl k+d autoformating

Comment: @ger Yeah, I know how to autoformate. I'm looking for a way to change the resulting format.